# Create category in in data-upgrade script

Tags: category, ce-1.8.1.0

I try to create categories with the following code in a data-upgrade script.
The categories where stored in the database but the seo-urls are not working.

Instead of *{HOST}/categoryA/categoryB* the url is like *{HOST}/catalog/category/view/s/categorB/id/152/*

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $rootCat */
$rootCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$rootCat->setPath('1/3')
    ->setIsActive('1')
    ->setName('foobar')
    ->save();


/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setPath($rootCat->getPath())
$category->setName($page->getData('title'));
$category->setMetaTitle($page->getData('pagetitle'));
$category->setIsActive(1);
$category->setIncludeInMenu(1);
$category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE');
$category->setIsAnchor(0);
$category->setPageLayout($page->getData('root_template'));
$category->setMetaKeywords($page->getData('meta_keywords'));
$category->setMetaDescription($page->getData('meta_description'));
$category->setColor($page->getData('color'));
$category->setBackground($page->getData('background'));
$category->save();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried reindexing?

Comment: are you sure all the URL rewrite modules are activated? (Apache and Magento)

Comment: @mbalparda It works after reindexing. Why is it necessary?

Comment: The reindex process updates the URLs as far as i know. I added an answer to this, please mark it as accepted so we can resolve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inserting the category reindex the indexes and that should fix your issue. You can add a reindex to your [code](http://www.codetweet.com/magento/reindexing-magento-programmaticaly/) also.